# Como acceder a un valor de una variable dentro de un evento actionPerformed java

Tags: java, netbeans

Como le puedo hacer para acceder al resultado de la variable tam, si observamos se obtiene dentro del evento, ese resultado lo quiero usar para otra operacion no me deja o no me permite, como le puedo hacer para poder usa ese resultado sin problema fuera de ese contexto, incluso la variable esta como global y no me deja

Introduzco un texto al campo de texto, lo que quiero es saber la cantidad de caracteres, y con esos mostrar las lineas que son para simular un juego del ahorcado y que el usuario adivine cada letra, pero no me permite sacar ese valor del evento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Abrir la misma pregunta una y otra vez no sirve de nada excepto que hacer que acaben cerradas

Comment: Esta pregunta se realizó previamente : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/612655/como-acceder-a-un-valor-de-una-variable-dentro-de-un-evento-actionperformed , te sugerimos revisar [ask] para que conozcas como puedas formular una pregunta y esta tenga buenas respuestas, saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: la variable esta declarada en la clase y todo el codigo lo tengo en el constructor, si observas tengo declarado un campo de texto el cual mediante el evento click me permite obtener el total de caracteres de esa palabra, lo que quiero es saber como acceder a ese valor y usarlo en el constructor, he intentado varias formas y no me deja, al momento que lo uso marca cero esa variable

Comment: como accedo a esa variable, la tengo como ambito global